# Is accepting domain objects as request payload in grpc an anti pattern?

Tags: protocol-buffers, microservices, grpc, grpc-java

I have a simple service which contains message definitions like

```
message BrandAttribute {
 option (gorm.opts) = {
    ormable: true
 };
 atlas.rpc.Identifier id = 1 [(gorm.field).tag = {type: "serial" primary_key: true}];
 string attribute_key = 2;
 string attribute_value = 3;
 atlas.rpc.Identifier brand_id = 4 [(gorm.field).tag = {not_null: true}];
 Status status = 5;
}

message Brand {
 option (gorm.opts) = {
    ormable: true
 };
 atlas.rpc.Identifier id = 1 [(gorm.field).tag = {type: "serial" primary_key: true}];
 atlas.rpc.Identifier external_id = 2 [(gorm.field).tag = {type: "text" unique: true}];
 string name = 3;
 string description = 4;
 string keywords = 5;
 string meta_keywords = 6;
 string meta_description = 7;
 repeated BrandAttribute brand_attributes = 8 [(gorm.field).has_many.foreignkey = "brand_id", (gorm.field).has_many.association_foreignkey = "id"];
 Status status = 9;
}
```

I have defined services for implementing CRUD operations on top of the above defined enity, but these services accept the Brand itself as the request payload(parameter) for create/update operations, is this approach correct ? if it isn't what is the best way to achieve this. Also if i wanna use JDBC for persitence i would have to decorate the Entities myself which protoc doesn't allow in the protobuf definition files, how can i achieve this as well ?

Answer (score 2):

A potential issue with using `Brand` as the request is that if you ever need to add additional information to the request, but don't want to add it to `Brand`, you will be stuck. A better practice is for each service method, always define dedicated request and response types for it. For your case, you'd make the `CreateRequest`, `UpdateRequest` messages etc, which contain `Brand`.

Comment: how will adding more attributes to `Brand` be avoided by encapsulating `Brand` inside `CreateRequest` and `UpdateRequest`?

Comment: Because you can add new attributes to `CreateRequest` instead of `Brand`.